# How to send WPS request using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wps

I have generated the WPS request below using GeoServer's `WPS Request Builder`. I wish to append more parameters to this request (geometry selection), and then send it either using GET or POST from within my OpenLayers JavaScript code. I can't seem to get information on how this can be done. How can I append geometry selection parameter to the request, and how can I send the request using OpenLayers? Any assistance will highly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:Aggregate</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2">
            <wfs:Query typeName="learning_workspace:pop_layer"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>aggregationAttribute</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>pop</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>function</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>Sum</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>singlePass</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>Yes</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

My environment: GeoServer 2.1.3, OpenLayers 2.11, PostGIS 1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorporate filters within the `<wfs:Query><wfs:Query/>` section in a `<Filter></Filter>`. The format of the filter is dependent on its type. More info on filters and examples is available [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/index.html) and [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html).

As for requests, I used OpenLayers' POST method to send request, as illustrated below:

```
var request = new OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: WPS_HOST,
        data: wpsRequestData,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=utf-8"
        },
        callback: function (response) {
            //read the response from GeoServer
            var gmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
            var xmlSum = gmlParser.read(response.responseText);
            // TODO: More operations here
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("Something went wrong in the request");
        }
    });
```

I hope this will be of help to someone.

Comment: can you give example in openlayers 3..?

Comment: @Priyanka I too waiting for the ol3 example for the WPS request builder Please share if u have the code my mail id is kamarajugaddamanjula@gmail.com