# Execute OpenLayers WPS request using WPS Client

Tags: openlayers-2, wps, wpsclient

I am having trouble executing WPS processes with the OpenLayers WPS Client. I can execute the processes in Geoserver, however when I try to execute the process from my OpenLayers test app I keep getting errors in my browsers javascript console relating to JSON and xmlhttprequest.

My JS code for creating the client, geometry and executing the process is below - In the Javascript console I can see the WPS  XML and it all looks well formed and good to go. Is the issue with my code trying to decipher the results? JS console image below.

[image]

```
    runoff = OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT('Point(148 -36)');

client = new OpenLayers.WPSClient({
    servers: {
        local: '/geoserver/wps'
    }
});

client.execute({
        server: 'local',
        process: 'gs:PointBuffers',
        inputs: {
            center: runoff,
            crs: 'EPSG:4326',
            distance: 1000
        },
        success: function(outputs) {
            for (var i=0, ii=outputs.result.length; i<ii; ++i) {
            alert(outputs.result[i].geometry.toString());
        }
        }
    });
```

Thanks Andrew

Comment: Ando, I have the same problem "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" the line is #97 "object = JSON.parse(json,filter); Have you found solution????????

Comment: Hey Lefox - I ended up building the WPS request in a different way and sending it to the server by OpenLayers Post request as shown in this SE article http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29382/how-to-send-wps-request-using-openlayers . Basically I copied the WPS request from Geoserver, stored it in a variable then used it in the Openlayers Post Request. A guy at work thinks the error is to do with my JSON response, he said that these issues tend to pop up when you receive a different mime type than the one you request or vice versa?! Not sure if this qualifies as a solution but it worked.

Comment: 1 vote for Ando, it runs smoothly. thks

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that the problem is about the runoff variable (WKT) you're passing, because JS console is complaining about an unexpected token, probably you need to wrap your geometry with double quotes rather than single quotes as shown here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WG8YP/4/

Here you can find some more discussions about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting the same result.

Comment: even though you use the WKT in the same way of the jsfiddle example? in any case, it would be good if you post code of the pointed lines in the console.

Comment: The lines that are mentioned in the JS console are referring to JS files that I have not created. I formed the WKT as you had in your JS fiddle example

Comment: what do they say? that's the question, you add that too to narrow down the problem.

Comment: The first error points to a line in the JSON.js file which reads "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" the line is #97 "object = JSON.parse(json,filter);

Comment: Bugger - I have run out of time and needed a solution. I can successfully create request and receive data by building the request in Geoserver and using OpenLayers.Request. So I have decided to go down this route - the WPS Client just looked like a simpler and cleaner solution. What should I do for the answer? My current solution doesn't answer the above question, and I would also like to reward Gery for the help he has provided.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jts_buffer</title>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/theme/default/style.css"> -->
     <link rel="stylesheet " href="http://dev.openlayers.org/theme/default/style.css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->

<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://dev.openlayers.org/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

   <div id="map" style="position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 802px;" ></div>
      <script>
 var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        allOverlays: true
    });
     var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
     var wpsClient = new OpenLayers.WPSClient({
    servers: {
        local: 'http://localhost:9999/geoserver/wps'
    } 
});
var wkt = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
var point = wkt.read(
   'POINT(615732.134982157 3344996.87257526)'
);

    var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");
    vectors.addFeatures([point]);
    map.addLayers([osm, vectors] );

    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

    wpsClient.execute({
    server: 'local',
    process: 'JTS:buffer',
    inputs: {
        geom: point ,
   distance: 5000000,
   quadrantSegments : 0,
   capStyle : 'Round'
    },
    success: function(outputs) {
         for (var i=0, ii=outputs.result.length; i<ii; ++i) {
            console.log(outputs);

            var polygonFeature = wkt.read(outputs.result[i].geometry.toString());
            bounds = polygonFeature.geometry.getBounds();    
            vectors.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
            map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
            //alert(outputs.result[i].geometry.toString());
        }
    }
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is an example of jts:buffer process please refer to it.

Comment: All code and no explanatory text generates a "low quality post" review queue event. Please frame your answer with some context.